# How can I determine browser window size on server side C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can I get the exact height and width of the currently open browser screen window?

Comment: I imagine you'd have to detect it with JavaScript and then pass it back to the server with an AJAX call.  (And update it any time it changes, or just hope it doesn't change.)  There's no way to determine this information _before_ rendering the page on the server-side.

Comment: Did you check `document.body.clientWidth` `document.body.clientHeight`

Comment: The C# code runs on the server, not on the client.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use Javascript to get the viewport width and height. Then pass the values back via a hidden form input or ajax.

### At its simplest

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
```

### Complete method using hidden form inputs

Assuming you have: [JQuery framework](http://jquery.com/).

First, add these hidden form inputs to store the width and height until postback.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="width" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="height" runat="server" />
```

Next we want to get the window (viewport) width and height. JQuery has two methods for this, aptly named width() and height().

Add the following code to your .aspx file within the head element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#width").val() = $(window).width();
    $("#height").val() = $(window).height();    

});
</script>
```

**Result**

This will result in the width and height of the browser window being available on postback. Just access the hidden form inputs like this:

```
var TheBrowserWidth = width.Value;
var TheBrowserHeight = height.Value;
```

This method provides the height and width upon postback, but not on the intial page load.

***Note on UpdatePanels:*** If you are posting back via UpdatePanels, I believe the hidden inputs need to be within the UpdatePanel.

Alternatively you can post back the values via an ajax call. This is useful if you want to react to window resizing.

**Update for jquery 3.1.1**

I had to change the JavaScript to:

```
$("#width").val($(window).width());
$("#height").val($(window).height());
```

Comment: this works to get the value into my hidden input, but the javascript fires after the Page_Load event, which is when I need the window height.  Is there no way for the page to know the window size in the Page_Load event?

Comment: matthew_360, have a look at Page.Request.Params[<your client id>] in Page_Load

Comment: @tony so how to get the window size before the page_load??? i dont understand the Page.Request.Params thingy!! can someone explain how to get this going??

Comment: @alinem, The first example puts the windows size in the hidden input, if you look at Page.Request.Params["width"] you can see this value in the Page_Load (or even OnInit). If this doesn't work look at the ClientID of the hidden value to see what the id is (might be something like myUserControl.Width)

Comment: @tony, the Page.Request.Params["Width"] in Page_Load is null even in Page_PreInit. and about the ClientID of the hidden value, i dont get it....here is my code:
head:
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () { $(function () { $('#mywidth').val($(window).width()); }); });
   </script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
body:
<body><form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:HiddenField ID="mywidth" runat="server"  />
Page_Load:
Label lblsz = new Label(); lblsz.Text = mywidth.Value;
the lblsz is still empty!!!!!

Comment: @alinem, (1) Your hidden field has an id of mywidth, you are looking at Page.Request.Params["Width"], different IDs. (2) Just look at Page.Request.Params.Keys to see a complete list of all the keys (3) In asp.net the ID of a control can be changed. You'd need to read up on that but ClientID is what it will be changed to

Comment: b.t.w. that's weird looking code, javascript inside a placeholder? 
And it should be lblsz.Text = Page.Request.Params["mywidth"], or you could just move that code to prerender

Comment: this might work, but I don't think this is the right way to go about doing it. What about Request.Browser object? Can't we determine the browser capabilities with that object?

Answer (score 5):

So here is how you will do it.

Write a javascript function which fires whenever the window is resized.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var height=$(window).height();
    var width=$(window).width();
    $.ajax({
     url: "/getwindowsize.ashx",
     type: "POST",
     data : { Height: height, 
              Width:width, 
              selectedValue:selectedValue },
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) { 
           // do stuff
     }

}
```

Codebehind of Handler:

```
 public class getwindowsize : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
     string Height = context.Request.QueryString["Height"]; 
     string Width = context.Request.QueryString["Width"]; 
    }
```

Comment: This is not a very good solution without event throttling. Please Google for the concept. To summarize, you're firing an AJAX call to the server every time the resize event happens in the client, which in Chrome and FF can be dozens of times a second as the user clicks and drags their browser's width. That's way too many AJAX calls!

Answer (score 4):

I went with using the regex from [detectmobilebrowser.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) to check against the `user-agent` string. Even tho it says it was last updated in 2014 it was accurate on the devices I tested.

Here is the `C#` code I got from them at the time of submitting this answer:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" %>
<%
    string u = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    Regex b = new Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Regex v = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    if ((b.IsMatch(u) || v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))) {
        Response.Redirect("http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile");
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to solve page_onload problem (can't get size until page load complete) : Create a userControl :

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ClientSizeDetector.ascx.vb"    Inherits="Project_UserControls_ClientSizeDetector" %>
<%If (IsFirstTime) Then%>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageURL = window.location.href.search(/\?/) > 0 ? "&" : "?";
window.location.href = window.location.href + pageURL + "clientHeight=" + window.innerHeight + "&clientWidth=" + window.innerWidth;
</script>
<%End If%>
```

Code behind :

```
 Private _isFirstTime As Boolean = False
 Private _clientWidth As Integer = 0
 Private _clientHeight As Integer = 0

 Public Property ClientWidth() As Integer
    Get
        Return _clientWidth
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _clientWidth = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ClientHeight() As Integer
    Get
        Return _clientHeight
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _clientHeight = value
    End Set
End Property

public Property IsFirstTime() As Boolean 
    Get
        Return _isFirstTime
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _isFirstTime = value
    End Set
End Property



Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)

    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("clientHeight")) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("clientWidth"))) Then
        Me._isFirstTime = True
    Else
        Integer.TryParse(Request.QueryString("clientHeight").ToString(), ClientHeight)
        Integer.TryParse(Request.QueryString("clientWidth").ToString(), ClientWidth)
        Me._isFirstTime = False
    End If
End Sub
```

So after, you can call your control properties

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Ajax, `asxh` handler and session variables approach:

**Handler:**

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class windowSize : IHttpHandler , System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState  {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var output = json.Serialize(new { isFirst = context.Session["BrowserWidth"] == null });
        context.Response.Write(output);

        context.Session["BrowserWidth"] =  context.Request.QueryString["Width"]; 
        context.Session["BrowserHeight"] = context.Request.QueryString["Height"];
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
    SetWidthHeight();
}
function SetWidthHeight() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    $.ajax({
        url: "windowSize.ashx",
        data: {
            'Height': height,
            'Width': width
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {     
        if (data.isFirst) {
            window.location.reload();
        };
    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        alert("Problem to retrieve browser size.");
    });

}
$(function () {
    SetWidthHeight();
});
```

**On aspx file:**

```
...
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/BrowserWindowSize.js"></script>
...
<asp:Label ID="lblDim" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
...
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (Session["BrowserWidth"] != null)
      {
          // Do all code here to avoid double execution first time
          // ....
          lblDim.Text = "Width: " + Session["BrowserWidth"] + " Height: " + Session["BrowserHeight"];
      }
  }
```

Source:  https://techbrij.com/browser-height-width-server-responsive-design-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Here how I solved it using Cookies:

First of all, inside the website main script:

```
var browserWindowSize = getCookie("_browserWindowSize");
var newSize = $(window).width() + "," + $(window).height();
var reloadForCookieRefresh = false;

if (browserWindowSize == undefined || browserWindowSize == null || newSize != browserWindowSize) {
    setCookie("_browserWindowSize", newSize, 30);
    reloadForCookieRefresh = true;
}

if (reloadForCookieRefresh)
    window.location.reload();

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And inside MVC action filter:

```
public class SetCurrentRequestDataFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // currentRequestService is registered per web request using IoC
        var currentRequestService = iocResolver.Resolve<ICurrentRequestService>();

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("_browserWindowSize"))
        {
            var browserWindowSize = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("_browserWindowSize").Value.Split(',');
            currentRequestService.browserWindowWidth = int.Parse(browserWindowSize[0]);
            currentRequestService.browserWindowHeight = int.Parse(browserWindowSize[1]);
        }

    }
}
```