# Call page_load form jquery ajax client side

Tags: asp.net, jquery, postback

I need to get user screen resolution on server side and resize controls according to resolution.

I have `asp:HiddenField` where I want to store resolution.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnScreenResolution" />
```

I have jquery ajax call that submits resolution:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      width = screen.width;
      height = screen.height;
      $.ajax({
         url: "Questionnaire.aspx/WindowResolutionSet",
         data: "{ 'width': '" + width + "', 'height' : '" + height + "'}",
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         sucess: function (msg) { alert("it works"); },
         error: function () { alert("error"); }
     });
 });
```

And web method for it:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool WindowResolutionSet(string width, string height)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

From WindowResolutionSet I can't access server controls on the page.

And `sucess: function (msg) { alert("it works");` does not fire.

I thought to populate `width` and `height` on `sucess` and then access it from `Page_Load()` but `sucess`does not fire. `error` does not execute as well.

There must be more efficient way, but I don't know it =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values are directly accessible using [HttpCapabilitiesBase.ScreenPixelsWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.screenpixelswidth.aspx) and [HttpCapabilitiesBase.ScreenPixelsHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.screenpixelsheight.aspx).

Example:

```
 var clientSize = new { 
      X = Page.Request.Browser.ScreenPixelWidth, 
      Y = Page.Request.Browser.ScreenPixelHeight
      };
 SomeMethod(clientSize.X, clientSize.Y);
```

Comment: it's the answer) but still curious how to do it through jquery ajax)

Comment: Actually, without this properties, I think you will have kind of hack to perform. You will have to call this webmethod, store in the viewstate or user session the detected resolution. Then reload the whole page to fire again the page_load event, where you can restore the viewstate or the session variable. Not as easy as this properties.

Comment: I will use your method, thanks) This curiosity just for educational reasons)

will do in free time

Comment: Just a warning. Like all properties available in the Browser object, these properties are inferred from the out of control browser user agent. A user (malicious or not) may have changed these values for some reason. It will works for the vast majority of user but there is a probability this won't.

Comment: Page.Request.Browser returns 640x480 as screen resolution and mine is 1920x1080

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628859/how-can-i-determine-browser-window-size-on-server-side-c-sharp) can help