# jquery window values are not accessible in asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have followed the answer written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628859/how-can-i-determine-browser-window-size-on-server-side-c-sharp)

but some how i am not able to get the values in my code behind.

below is my code sample

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#width").val() = $(window).width();
                $("#height").val() = $(window).height();
                });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:HiddenField ID="width" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="height" runat="server" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="MySearchButton" runat="server" Height="38" ImageUrl="~/Images/search-button-without-text-md.png" OnClick="MySearchButton_Click" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my code behind

```
protected void MySearchButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   var BrowserWidth = width.Value;
   var BrowserHeight = height.Value;
}
```

but some how i am not able to get the height and width of the browser. the values are empty. can some one suggest me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Your syntax is basically "object.method() = value". That syntax just does not make sense. Remember, jQuery is JUST a set of objects and functions provided by a library, it does NOT alter the JS language in such a way to make methods accept assignment values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#width").val($(window).width());
    $("#height").val($(window).height());
});
```

`$.prototype.val` acts as a hybrid get/set ie getter when called w/o argument and setter w/ argument. `$inst.val()` - get field value. `$inst.val(value)` - set field value.

Comment: it worked like a charm. thanks yury. Can u explain me whats was wrong? the synatx?

Comment: @RitheshBaradi Brief explanation added.

Comment: hi yury, sorry to trouble you again. after hosting my web application on IIS server, this things works fine on other browsers except IE. in IE there is no value for window height and width. any thoughts on that??

Comment: @RitheshBaradi Hmm. It works for me (I've checked IE10). Do you have doctype specified on your page? `<!DOCTYPE html>`