# Browser width by razor server side

Tags: c#, razor, browser, viewport

I know how to hide and show the part of page by using CSS and media.

Look the code bellow to understand requirement:

```
@if (browserWidth > 1300)
{
    <div id="extwidth-ads" >
        Add will go here and will only be rendered for bigger browsers
    </div>
}
```

Above ad section will only be rendered (not show/hide) when browser size will be greater than 1300px.

If I will use the JavaScript to get the browser width, razor will already be called this section and all the codes to render the ads, which I don't want.

Is there really any way to find the width on server side?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11629035/4228458)

Comment: Read 2nd paragraph from last, I don't want to use the JavaScript because JS will be called only after page load

Comment: The link was (likely) to give you the idea that you _will_ still use Javascript to (1) Obtain client properties (viewport, etc), then (2) make an AJAX call, _only if/when appropriate_, to inject content into some DOM target (e.g. `id="extwidth-ads"`). Nothing is rendered, nor called, on initial load. Hth.

Comment: What I meant is that you can do that and send the browser width info to the server, get the ad and then inject it into the page.